# Build a string and use it as an html object: Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, core-ui

I'm trying to build a React app. I have a dropdown menu component where each item is a combination of an array. Here is my code:

```js
class PlotCardMenu extends React.Component {
  renderMenuItems(m) {
    let indices = Array(m)
      .fill(0)
      .map((v, i) => i);
    let it = new Combination(indices, 3);
    let menuItems = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < it.length; i++) {
      let item = "[" + it
        .nth(i)
        .map((e) => "f<sub>" + e + "</sub>")
        .join(",") + "]";
      console.log(item); // for sanity check
      menuItems.push(<CDropdownItem key={i}>{item}</CDropdownItem>);
    }
    return menuItems;
  }

  render() {
    return <CDropdownMenu>{this.renderMenuItems(4)}</CDropdownMenu>;
  }
}
```

Now if I look at the component, I'm not getting the html rendered. What I want each item to look like this: `[f_0, f_1, f_2]`, where `f_0` means `f-subscript-0` etc.

[image: Output]

So I did some googling and found that I need to convert the string into html object. So I tried like this:

```js
renderMenuItems(m) {
    let indices = Array(m)
      .fill(0)
      .map((v, i) => i);
    let it = new Combination(indices, 3);
    let menuItems = [];
    let parser = new DOMParser();
    for (let i = 0; i < it.length; i++) {
      let item = "[" + it
        .nth(i)
        .map((e) => "f<sub>" + e + "</sub>")
        .join(",") + "]";
      console.log(item);
      let doc = parser.parseFromString(item, "text/html");
      menuItems.push(<CDropdownItem key={i}>{doc}</CDropdownItem>);
    }
    return menuItems;
  }
```

and I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDocument]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

How do I solve it?

Note: `CDropdownItem` and `CDropdownMenu` are from [coreui-react](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-react) and `Combination` is from `js-combinatorics`.

Comment: Why are you using strings? You're in React, building a React interface: construct proper React components. E.g. `map((e) => <span>f<sub>{e}</sub></span>)`, no strings. Just direct, real, React component using JSX syntax.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans what I want is each `f<sub>{e}</sub>` is separated by commas and surrounded by '[ ]', like this: `[f0, f1, f2]`. How do I do that?

Comment: If you want something that you didn't describe in your post, please update your post. Don't add more details in comments, instead update your post and then comment that you've done so. And again: if you need content, _build that content_: you don't want an array of strings, you want _content on the page_ that has commas, so make that part of the content you generate: `list.map((e,pos) => <span>f<sub>{e}</sub>{pos < list.length-1 ? ', ' : ''}</span>)`. Don't build DOM content, build React content and let React sort out how it renders that.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It was there in the screenshots though also in the code, most probably the `item = "[" + ` was not noticeable, but anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are sending an array of string that's why it render array as a string so don't try to convert string to HTML Object. You have to send Array in place of string:

```
class PlotCardMenu extends React.Component {
renderMenuItems(m) {
    let indices = Array(m)
        .fill(0)
        .map((v, i) => i);
    let it = new Combination(indices, 3);
    let menuItems = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < it.length; i++) {
        let item = it
            .nth(i)
            .map((e) => (<span>f<sub>{e}</sub></span>))
        console.log(item); // for sanity check
        menuItems.push(<CDropdownItem key={i}>{item}</CDropdownItem>);
    }
    return menuItems;
}

render() {
    return <CDropdownMenu>{this.renderMenuItems(4)}</CDropdownMenu>;
}
 }
```

I think it will resolve your problem.

Comment: What I want is each `f<sub>{e}</sub>` is separated by commas and surrounded by `[ ]`, like this: `[f_0, f_1, f_2]`, where `f_0` means `f-subscript-0`. How do I do that?

Comment: Also I'm getting this warning `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

Comment: In that case replace "<span>f<sub>{e}</sub></span>" code with <span>{\`f_${e}\`}</span>

Comment: And I don't get why do u need array?

Comment: If u want to show [f_0, f_1, f_2] then u just make string like this one("[f_0, f_1, f_2]") then u don't need array. If u want some operation on that array in that case above code will work.